# Excel VBA: Comparing two excel sheets and conditionally formatting based off extra data from sheet 2

Tags: vba, excel

I'm sort of creating a dashboard view that will have formatting determined by other sheets on the file.

Dashboard will have a checkbox that indicates which sheet it will read from. I'm still working on the first sheet.

Basically the dashboard has names that are placed in different parts of the sheet and the second sheet will have corresponding names in a spreadsheet like fashion.

I'm trying to write something that basically compares the range of names to the list of names on sheet two, if the names match, I want it to read the number next to the name on sheet 2 and calculate then format the name on sheet 1. Here is sample code

```
Dim processes As Range
Dim applications As Range
Dim appCount As Range
Dim k As Integer

Set process = Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("A4:F17")
Set applications = Worksheets("Application").Cells(2, 1)
Set appCount = Worksheets("Application").Cells(2, 2)

k = 0

For I = 1 To process.Rows.Count
    For j = 1 To process.Columns.Count
        If process.Cells(I, j) = applications.Offset(k, 0) Then
            If appCount.Offset(k, 0) >= 40 Then
                process.Cells(I, j).Interior.ColorIndex = 37
            Else
                If appCount.Offset(k, 0) >= 20 Then
                    process.Cells(I, j).Interior.ColorIndex = 32
                Else
                    If appCount.Offset(k, 0) <= 19 Then
                        process.Cells(I, j).Interior.ColorIndex = 27
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
        k = k + 1
    Next j
Next I
```

Basically I want it to match names and compare the value in the next cell over on sheet 2 to determine the formatting for the name on sheet 1.

Thank you to anyone who is able to help. I keep getting an error when I try to run this. Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method.

Comment: Please use **indenting** when posting code if you're expecting people to read it.  Also please indicate which line throws the error

Comment: I used the code tag.  Sorry I fixed the naming thing and no more error code. it just colors the wrong boxes now.

Comment: Insert [Option Explicit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278855.aspx) at the top of the module (before the very first line of code). `process` is currently **not** declared in your code.

Comment: On which line do you get the error?

Comment: Why don't you use conditional formatting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would propose to use conditional formatting, like this:

[image]

The Formulas you need are the following:

```
=40<IFERROR(INDEX($AB$1:$AB$2,MATCH($A1,$AA$1:$AA$2,0)),"Other")
=20<IFERROR(INDEX($AB$1:$AB$2,MATCH($A1,$AA$1:$AA$2,0)),"Other")
=0<IFERROR(INDEX($AB$1:$AB$2,MATCH($A1,$AA$1:$AA$2,0)),"Other")
```

Please note that the order of the rules is important, you should start with the one starting as =40<.

Comment: hi, thanks for the response, I haven't tried this yet, but I was going to go the conditional formatting route but I plan to have more conditions and plan to normalize each of the criteria to be able to merge and change the color if needed. This was kind of a test round to see if I can get the initial code to run. I plan to have a dashboard with several checkboxes across the top and they will format according to what is checked. so if box 1 and 2 are checked. they will pull the normalized score from each and create a new number to format against. I will give this a shot. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want to use VBA, then note that the main problem with your code is not language specific but that you did not get the algorithm right. Currently you compare process 1 1 only with application 1, then process 1 2 only with application 2, ... process m n with application 14×m+n. To keep thinks simple, you should have a third loop to iterate all rows of applications, like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate() ' Or Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim processes As Range
    Dim applications As Range
    Dim appCount As Range
    Dim k As Integer

    Set process = Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("A4:F17")
    Set applications = Worksheets("Application").Cells(2, 1)
    Set appCount = Worksheets("Application").Cells(2, 2)

    For i = 1 To process.Rows.Count
        For j = 1 To process.Columns.Count
            For k = 0 To applications.End(xlDown).Row - 2
                If process.Cells(i, j) = applications.Offset(k, 0) Then
                    If appCount.Offset(k, 0) >= 40 Then
                        process.Cells(i, j).Interior.ColorIndex = 37
                    ElseIf appCount.Offset(k, 0) >= 20 Then
                        process.Cells(i, j).Interior.ColorIndex = 32
                    ElseIf appCount.Offset(k, 0) <= 19 Then
                        process.Cells(i, j).Interior.ColorIndex = 27
                    End If
                End If
            Next k
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

As you can see I put it into an Event handler. This way it will update the colors any time you turn to the worksheet in question. Alternatively, you may bind it to Worksheet_Change, so it will be updated whenever something changes on your process sheet (more frequent updates but needs more CPU time).

Please not that for large datasets this algorithm is not optimal but you should use a two phase approach: (1) Collect all application-applicationCount pairs or even application-formatting instruction pairs into a Scripting.Dictionary and (2) iterate all cells of process, lookup application in the dictionary and apply formatting according to it. This would be more efficient since time needed to search in dictionaries is proportional to log(applications) instead of to applications.